# I am trying to automate Goibibo in Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate `Goibibo Website` in `Selenium` using `Java`. After Clicking on `Search` options there are lot of tabs with `BOOK` option.

On Inspect, All tabs have same `X-Path`. How to select one of them?

Following is the Code:

```
<input type="button" value="BOOK" class="button orange fr fn ft_bookbtn ">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indexes

```
List<WebElement> books = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[value='BOOK']"));
books.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take the first on you can also use

```
    WebElement book = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[value='BOOK']"));
```

if you want random selection you can do this:

```
    List<WebElement> books = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[value='BOOK']"));
    int r = new Random(books.length).nextInt();
    WebElement book = books.get(r);
```